# What's an equivalent to Meteor.startup in Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, webpack, storybook

I've been trying to integrate Vulcan.js, a Meteor framework, with Storybook. The difficulty comes from the differences in build system. Currently, we are able to load some specific Meteor packages in Storybook using Webpack.

So, now we need to mimick some additional Meteor features in Storybook. We rely on a `Meteor.startup()` callback to initialize a specific React component that is a registry of other components. However I can't find any equivalent pattern in Storybook.

The characteristic of a callback registered with `Meteor.startup()` are as following:

- it is run `after` the app is build. So it is not possible to just write a "startup" file and import it, because it will run too soon, the registry will still be empty
- it is run `before` stories are actually rendered or loaded. Basically `Meteor.startup` callbacks are guaranteed to be the first function to be run. So calling relevant function in a decorator may be too late.
- it is called only once. This is not a strong requirement as we can bypass it by writing callbacks as pure function but it's better to avoid multiple calls.

I've tried writing an addon, but it does not work as addons have their own build system. Therefore they can't access our Meteor packages and yet they need them to work correctly.

I've tried writing a decorator. That's an okay solution but I have strange behaviour, because it runs the startup function on every component mount (that's the only way to run them after import but before render). That's my best bet currently but it seems suboptimal.

Last solution is running the code at the top of relevant stories. It works but it's error prone and affects the developer experience

So, here is the question: how would you define a callback in Storybook so that it is run during startup, like `Meteor.startup` callbacks do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dig into it, on the client `Meteor.startup` is just a wrapper around `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func)`

So it should be easy to replicate by listening for the event

Comment: Good idea I should have checked this indeed. The question then is where to put this code, I'll update if I figure this out.

Comment: This worked well, I wrote a startup function based on Meteor.startup implementation here and called it inside the config file: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/24865b28a0689de8b4949fb69ea1f95da647cd7a/packages/meteor/startup_client.js

Answer (score 1):

Ideally any React components that you are writing stories for should be pure render components, and should not reference anything Meteor specific, like `Meteor...`.

The usual approach is to write a container component, which does things like loading data (eg using `withTracker()`), and calling any Meteor functions needed. It should pass utility functions as props to the component.

Storybook merely needs to provide these functions as props - you can use the actions add-on: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-actions

> ## Storybook Addon Actions
>
> Storybook Addon Actions can be used to display data received by event handlers in  [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/).

At first this will seem difficult, but it's actually good practice in any environment to keep components pure. Their job is to provide rendering, and pass events to the logic and apis (which live elsewhere). It also means that the components can be re-used (even in non-meteor projects), and are easier to test, because you don't need to mockup your meteor environment)

Comment: Sorry but this is out of scope. Here what we wanted is not to mock/remove Meteor but to create a function with the same specification as `Meteor.startup` or jQuery's `$()`, but for Storybook : run after the imports, but before the rendering. Having Meteor outside of the visual component is indeed a good practice but you can't guarantee that this pattern is 100% respected in a real life application. In Vulcan we rely on the Meteor package system a lot, in the application themselves, which makes this subdivision possible but very verbose, at least at the moment.

Comment: Yes, of course, I understand your position, and in an ideal world we can author React components that are usable outside Meteor as well. There is some effort involved in doing it, and it's hard to enforce, especially if your code base hasn't done it that way.